# Is there a way to delete all the data from a stolen computer as the option in " google find my device " , in case the computer is lost or stolen

Tags: windows, data-recovery, online-backup

I have this security question: is there a way to delete all the data from a stollen computer as the option in " google find my device " Thanks

Comment: Windows doesn’t have a way built in to remotely wipe devices

Answer (score 0):

It would have to have been configured before it was lost. If it is Microsoft intune joined you can use endpoint manager to wipe it. Apple has something similar. You don't have to wipe the device if it is encrypted.